# py.test: How to avoid naming every test? Generate the test name dynamically

Tags: pytest

Occasionally I name tests like `test_X1`, `test_X2`,...
because

- it is always about feature X and
- the tests are small and
- I don't want a descriptive name that is longer than the test

Especially when things still change a lot I don't want to think of a name at all.

The line where the test resides defines the test in the file.

So how to use the line for the test name?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to name the tests dynamically `test_<line>`.

```
from inspect import currentframe
def namebyline(f):
    line = currentframe().f_back.f_lineno
    globals()['test_' + str(line)] = f
@namebyline
def _(): # becomes test_6
    assert True
@namebyline
def _(): #becomes test_9
    assert False
```